# Why my php script spends too much time?

Tags: php, parsing, http-authentication

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. This script takes almost 50 sec to execute. I am using simple_html_dom_parser to parse URL from database. Parsing goes well and spends 8 sec, but the rest of the code takes a lot of time.

```
include('config.php');
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$query_select = "select `nasname`,`username`,`password` from `nas`";
$result_select = mysql_query($query_select);
$web_parser = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
{  
   $host = $row['nasname'];
   $port = '5006';
   $url='http://'.$row['nasname'].':5006/';
   $username = $row['username'];
   $password = $row['password'];
   $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
 if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){                    
   $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
        )); 
$data = file_get_html($url,true,$context);
foreach($data->find('tr') as $row) { 
        $users = $row->find('td',9)->plaintext;
        $web_parser[$users] = $users; 
        echo $users;
   }
$data->clear(); 
unset($data);
}   }
```

Comment: Add `$startTime=mktime(); $logPos=0;` to the very beginning of the file (before `include('config.php')`) and then add `echo ($logPos++).'-'.(mktime()-$startTime());` after every significant line (every line that does something that might take time). That way you will be able to see which lines take long time to execute and you can work from there.

Comment: So, 50 seconds to process how many sites? One? A hundred? A thousand?

Comment: Your runtime is proportional to how many rows returned from the dbquery, not only on the parsing time of DOM. If it takes 8 secs to parse a single response, then for 6 rows it will take 48 secs.

Comment: What @SaravanaKumar said, plus the time from accessing and retrieving the page given none of those actually time out which would make your process wait until the page times out.

Comment: So, 50 seconds to process how many sites? - 2 sites